# programatically define a TextView within a LinearLayout in one line

Tags: android, layout, textview, short

I know this is possible to do in multiple lines like this:

```
    LinearLayout table=new LinearLayout(this);
    TextView titleText = new TextView(this);
    titleText.setText("Med Info");
    LinearLayout table=new LinearLayout(this);
    table.addView(titleText);
```

Is there a way to do this in one line without using XML? I already tried this:

```
LinearLayout table=new LinearLayout(this);
    table.addView(new TextView(this).setText("Med Info"));
```

which did not work (Wrong return value). I checked the TextView constructor, but nothing seemed to fit my goal. I am merely trying to shorten already existing code, not a serious project.

Comment: it is the method `addView`which excpect a `View`in parameter, an you are passing `void`because the method `setText()`return void

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible without creating a wrapper function, since both `.addView()` and `.setText()` return `void`.

You should have no need to do this anyway. Readability is *far* more important than compressing lines of code.

Comment: +1 for readability. I once saw a single line of `C` code which 'compressed' about 6 or 7 lines into one. I actually had to pull it apart and re-create the individual lines before I could make sense of it.

Comment: Very true, I realize that this is not a practical problem, I was merely curious.